# does monkey runner need source code to automate the app?

Tags: android, monkeyrunner

I am new to monkey runner.

Does it need sourcecode to test?  I can test only native app or 3rd party app also..

It would be great if any could let me know this..

Thanks

Comment: Also Please let me know that assertion is available on Monkey Runner?

Comment: There is no need for source code. You just need the pixel info or the input events, thats all. Not sure about assertion but you can apply conditions.

Comment: Input events means onClick(), onTouch()...? Those are all keyboard comments right? Please correct me if i am wrong..

Comment: You can send touch events with status DOWN, UP, DOWN and UP, drag and also the key events like any key, HOME, menu key etc.

Comment: Thanks..will it be possible to select check box, radio button and drop down also?

Comment: why not? you just have to send either the touch event to chechbox or more preciously go to that menu by sending keycode up/down and then send the KEYCODE_ENTER to check/uncheck.

Comment: Excellent!!! I have changed my monkeyrunner.jar to monkeyrunner_original. Now do i need to install python interpretor with the monkey runner name in the eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

Although this question is quite old and might be answered for you already, I'm hoping on helping someone else with this answer.

You can use MonkeyRunner without source-code, but that way you can only simulate actions on objects in the applications using the objects' coordinates. See the function `void touch (integer x, integer y, integer type)` on http://developer.android.com/tools/help/MonkeyDevice.html for example.

Personally, I don't like working like that. Finding out an objects' coordinates is very extensive and tools such as MonkeyTalk (http://www.gorillalogic.com/monkeytalk) provide scripting options (actually, you might not even need to script, since it has a great record and play feature) using object's IDs.

**However**, the latest versions of Android's monkeyrunner provide an extension called EasyMonkeyDevice. This class allows you to find object IDs and use them in monkeyrunner functions such as the earlier mentioned `touch()`. If you want to use objects' IDs, you might want to have the source code of the application to look them up. Check out this blog post about EasyMonkeyDevice: http://dtmilano.blogspot.ca/2012/01/monkeyrunner-testing-views-properties.html. A BIG disadvantage of EasyMonkeyDevice is that there is no (official) documentation whatsoever.

I'm using monkeyrunner myself at the moment and I'm trying to find out some more information about (the usage of) EasyMonkeyDevice. At the moment I'm planning on diving into the SDK's source code, but I haven't found that either yet. If I  have some more detailed information, I will post it here (-: